# Releasing GIL with custom Python objects in Cython?

Tags: python, cython, python-multithreading, gil, cythonize

I'm trying to multi-thread some code for work. Multi-processing takes too much memory because the data sets are not shared throughout each process, but cloned for each one. That is, rather than 25/25/25/25 for 4 processes, I have 100/100/100/100.

Since Python uses the Global Interpreter Lock, multi-threading runs concurrently and everything is slower than if I didn't use it at all - so I'm trying to use Cython and releasing the gil using `with nogil:`. I am aware of the restriction of manipulating Python objects, but is there a way to simply reference one without actually manipulating it?

Currently, I have two files (they're large, so I'll just show a similar structure):

vecmodeltest.pyx

```
    cpdef int run_me(string w, vector[string] doc, vectormodel):
        cdef int count=0
        cdef string t
        with nogil:
            for t in doc:
                if vecmodel.simi(w,t)>0.2:
                    count+=1
    return count
```

vecmodel.py

```
    import vecmodeltest as vm
    
    class VecModel(object):
       def _init_(self):
          pass
       def simi(self, w1,w2):
          s1 = set(w1)
          s2 = set(w2)
          i = len(s1.intersection(s2))
          return float(i / len(s1.union(s2)))
    
    _word = "hello"
    doc = "hello this is a hell document".split()
    vecmodel = VecModel()
    
    vm.run_me(_word, doc, vecmodel)
```

I get an error for `vecmodeltest.pyx:6:35: Converting to Python object not allowed without gil` when trying to build the Cython file, for this line: `if vecmodel.simi(w,t)>0.2:`. I've tried entering and exiting GIL in different places throughout the file, but keep struggling to work with the Python object.

Maybe I'm approaching this problem wrong, but are there any current solutions to working with custom Python objects in Cython?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You need the GIL for what you're trying to do. Cython doesn't let you just make the GIL go away.

Comment: Even if there were a clear line between "manipulating" and "referencing" Python objects, do you have any idea how many Python objects you're manipulating inside `simi`?

Comment: You could use a `cdef` method of a `cdef class` that only takes C objects as arguments without the GIL. But that would require rewriting every line of your current code to something completely different

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was worried about - I was just hoping there was a chance there was something I hadn't thought of. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Best to convert the documents and words into sets, then run the similarity without passing the class object. This wat you can use Multi-processing without having to pass a large model.